# How to create IAM group and user in AWS using powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

1   I am using PowerShell and want to run following command New-IAMGroup -Path "/ps-created-groups/" -GroupName "powerUsers", but getting below error

New-IAMGroup : The term 'New-IAMGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- New-IAMGroup -Path "/ps-created-groups/" -GroupName "powerUsers"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-IAMGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

How can this be resolved? I am new to Powershell.Your help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The powershell cli for AWS does not install service specific cmdlets. You need to install them yourself.
See AWS documentation for this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-windows.html

For IAM this will help you install the right cmdlets.

`Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.IdentityManagement -Scope AllUsers`

And then try to run your commands.

P.S. change the scope from `AllUsers` to `CurrentUser` as needed.